# C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 75, Column: 57 --- Internal Error

Tags: c++, windows-forms-designer

I Know this question has been asked before (many times) But I can't seem to find the answer.

I have dragged a TestBox onto the form, which generated the code in the 
`void InitializeComponent(void)` method for me. When I add this line however:

`this->MyTextBox->Text = DateTime::Now.ToString();`

It comes up with the error in the title when I open the designer?
My question is, why this is happening; and how to get rid of it.

This is the entire code for the page:

```
#pragma once

namespace Project1 {



    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  MyTextBox;
    protected: 

    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

        //MAIN METHOD FOR FORM

        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->MyTextBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(132, 123);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"Callum Holden";
            this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label1_Click);
            // 
            // MyTextBox
            // 
            this->MyTextBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(54, 183);
            this->MyTextBox->Name = L"MyTextBox";
            this->MyTextBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->MyTextBox->TabIndex = 1;
            this->MyTextBox->Text = L"g" + DateTime::Now.ToString();



            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(308, 275);
            this->Controls->Add(this->MyTextBox);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }


#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             }
    };
}
```

Thankyou for any suggestions!,

Callum

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/465452/DateTime-Format-in-Cplusplus-WinForm))

```
this->MyTextBox->Text = DateTime::Now->ToString();
```